# mpc: access denied when adding mp3 file in a folder under music_directory

Tags: arch-linux, mpd

`mpc rescan` `mpc update` give same result.

mpd.conf, mpd service running under user.

```bsh
music_directory       "~/.cache/music"
playlist_directory    "~/.config/mpd/playlists"
db_file               "~/.config/mpd/database"

input {
        plugin "curl"
}

audio_output {
       type   "pulse"
       name   "Local Music Player Daemon"
       server   "127.0.0.1"
}
```

I can `mpc add` file under `~/.cache/music`, but I can't `mpc add` file under a folder of `~/.cache/music`, e.g: `~/.cache/music/my music folder`, it gives error:

> error adding /home/user/.cache/music/my music folder/20. whatever.mp3:
>   Access denied

`mpc search title "20. whatever"` gives an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is late, but I only saw your message today.
Try to uncomment in mpd.conf the two lines :

```
follow_outside_symlinks     "yes"
follow_inside_symlinks      "yes"
```

I hope this will help you or anyone else.
I had the same problem and it fixed it.

Comment: did not help me at least :/